# Combining many result sets of the same detail into one Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am querying an API with which is giving me a response like below:

```
{
  "clients": {
    "one": {
      "id": "iphone6p_9",
      "category": "Mobile"
    },
    "two": {
      "id": "gmail_chr26_win",
      "category": "Web"
    },
    "three": {
      "id": "outlook16",
      "category": "Application"
    }
  }
}
```

Which would be below in a c# class

```
public class One
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

public class Two
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

public class Three
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

public class Clients
{
    public One one { get; set; }
    public Two two { get; set; }
    public Three three { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Clients clients { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible using Newtonsoft.Json to dynamically put One ,Two and Three into the same type as they are the same as oppose to being individual x times. Like a List

Comment: make `Clients clients` a `Dictionary<string, Client>`... (with `Client` being a renamed version of `One`)

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, One>`.

Comment: Why have you created three classes at all? Why don't you just have a single class and use that for all three properties in `Clients`? (Or have a `Dictionary<string, One>` as others have suggested. It's slightly unclear whether the problem is having multiple types or multiple properties.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for your purpose:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class Clients
{
    public Client One { get; set; }

    public Client Two { get; set; }

    public Client Three { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Clients Clients { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialization:

```
var clients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(*jsonStringHere*);
```